# How to use Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for automated tests

Tags: e2e-testing, azure-ad-msal

How do I use MSA or [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) to test client code against both business and consumer test accounts in the same test suite without any user interaction? Windows Integrated Auth is not an option for this, and is [not implemented](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/662a12c251811f332a14bb6ea196e23793f3bf4f/src/MSAL.PCL/PublicClientApplication.cs#L212) in MSAL even if I was running on the domain.

For ADAL, there is this blog post, [Using ADAL .NET to Authenticate Users via Username/Password](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/), but my understanding is that this option is not encouraged and may be disabled in the future. Plus, I can't use this for consumer accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The current MSAL preview only silent flows for user based auth all rely on the presence of cached tokens, previously obtained via interactive authentication.
Chances are that this will be the case for the next preview as well. The domain based integrated authentication will eventually be supported. However the current plan of record for username and password grant is that the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint will not support it.

Comment: So, does this mean, for automated tests, I'd need to get a refresh token via interactive authentication, manually add it to a cache, and request access tokens based on the refresh token? I'm looking for a solution for continuous integration and tests.

Comment: Not manually. Every time you invoke AcquireToken*, tokens are automatically added to the cache. What you do need to do is supplying a cache implementation that uses the persistence layer of your choice, e.g. a file, so that you can reuse it wherever you are running your tests.